# How can I move the cursor in block mode (without changing the block)?

Tags: visual-block

When a visual block is created, the block itself is highlighted, but the cursor is highlighted differently, green in my terminal.

If I want the block to stay the same but move just the location of the green cursor, how do I do that?

I want to do this so I can try to make a block edit at the beginning of a line. For example:

```
<C-v>4j$?2x
```

where the '?' is the motion I need to get the cursor back to the beginning of the block. If I do this without moving the cursor, then the whole block gets deleted, instead of just the first 2 characters in the block.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `o` visual command which will go to the other end of the visually selected text. There is also `O` which moves within the same line.

For more help see:

```
:h v_o
```

Comment: Wow. I use `v_o` often, but I never knew about `v_O`. Thanks! :D